# Modelica differential equations

Tags: modelica

I am going through Modelica libraries. I was wondering, that there are (or i can't found them) ODE's.

For example in the [dynamic pipe model of the standard library](http://www.maplesoft.com/documentation_center/online_manuals/modelica/Modelica_Fluid_Pipes.html#Modelica.Fluid.Pipes.DynamicPipe).

Answer (score 6):

Generally, the Modelica Standard Library contains many dynamic models - i.e. models that can be described with DAEs or ODEs (look for models using the `der()` operator).

The reason why you don't see any `der()` operators in `DynamicPipe` is that it inherits much of its functionality from several base classes - including `Modelica.Fluid.Interfaces.PartialDistributedVolume` where you will find the differential equation for mass and energy balances.

`Modelica.Blocks.Continuous.FirstOrder` is an example of a very simple ODE - a first-order low-pass filter.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to consult the free online Modelica book ["Modelica by Example"](http://book.xogeny.com/).  It shows many examples involving ordinary differential equations.